# ActiveAdmin formtastic link_to on a collection leading to the show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, collections, activeadmin, formtastic, link-to

Just wondering about how to have this link to this to the appropriate supplier_company_view with clickable names. The .to_sentence is optional.

```
column :supply_companies do |pt|
 pt.supply_companies.collect {|c| c.company_name.capitalize }.to_sentence
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can do it this way but not sure if it is the best way.

```
column :supply_companies do |pt|
 pt.supply_companies.map { |cn| link_to cn.company_name, 
 admin_supply_companies_path + "\/" + cn.id.to_s }.join(", ").html_safe
end
```